# How to fwrite to pointer of pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, fwrite

I have a function which should store content of a `file` to pointer of pointer - `content`. When I am trying to check the result of `fwrite` function - it returns nothing to `writn`. What am I doing wrong here? Did I allocate memory correctly (if I want to copy the whole file)?

```
bool load(FILE* file, BYTE** content, size_t* length)
{
    int len = 0, writn = 0;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    *length = len = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    *content = (char) malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char)); //(len + 1) * sizeof(char)

    writn = fwrite(*content, len + 1, 1, file);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: First problem might be the cast `(char)` instead of `(char*)`.

Comment: And in fact, you don't need to cast at all.

Comment: @OlafDietsche This being C, there should be no cast at all.

Comment: You assig to `writn` and never use it, and you also try to write uninitialized data to the file, is this on purpose?

Comment: Where do you see, that `writn` isn't assigned a value?

Comment: Briefly: enable compiler warnings and fix them first before asking for debugging help. Then see [ask] and provide a [mcve]. You are not a newbie here, should know how it works.

Comment: Why do you use `fwrite` if you want to read from the file? Doesn't the **write** versus **read** ring a bell

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `fwrite()`?

Comment: I should use fread function instead, sorry for confusion..

Comment: Consider having  function returning a `FILE*` on success (and `NULL` on failure).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yes I did, main checks that.

Comment: What I meant is to have your `load` function be declared as `FILE*load(`....`)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably opened the file for reading `"r"` mode and `fwrite()` will write into the file, not read. If this is the case `fwrite()` will fail of course.

Perhaps you simply need

```
// Use long int for `length' to avoid a problem with `ftell()'
// read the documentation
bool load(FILE* file, BYTE **content, long int *length)
{
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    *length = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    if (*length == -1)
        return false;    
    *content = malloc(*length + 1);
    if (*content == NULL)
        return false;
    if (fread(*content, 1, *length, file) != *length) {
        free(*content);
        *content = NULL;
        return false;
    }
    (*content)[*length] = '\0';
    return true;
}
```

You also, try to "*read*" more data than available, since you get the file length and still try to read 1 more byte.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was intended to do

Comment: Doesn't `ftell()` return `long`, and `-1` on failure?  Saving the result as a `size_t` breaks that.  Also, `fread()` is almost certain to fail to return the same value stored in `*length` if the file is opened in text mode on Windows, or any other platform that where the result of `ftell()` isn't representative of the number of bytes read from a text file.

Answer (score 2):

What I see this function do is:

- determine the size of the file;
- allocate a chunk of memory that size;
- write that chunk to the file.

This assumes that `file` is opened for reading and writing. The `fseek` seeks to the end of the file (a read operation); following the `rewind` the chunk is written (write operation). If the file is only opened for writing, then `fseek` will probably fail, so your size will be zero. If the file is only open for reading, then your `fwrite` will fail. In addition, tou write uninitialized data to the file (the allocated memory has not been ininitialized).

Is this what it is supposed to do?

Comment: The function name is `load()` I think it's purpose is to load the file contents as a string.

Comment: @Paul Ogivie, thank you for the answer. This function supposed to read the file to that chunk of memory. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So in the functional descripton, my third bullet should be "read the file into tht chunk" and you should have used `fread` where you use `frwite`. Was that late-night programming?